# postfix gateway reject incoming spoofed emails from my domain

Tags: email, postfix

I have a postfix gateway.  It only allows emails from the outside to a list of internal users in mydomain.com and it allow emails from my internal mail server to go out to the internet.  There is no authentication happening on the gateway.

I would like a simple way to reject any incoming emails with a from address in mydomain.com while still allowing outgoing emails from my internal mail server (preferably only ones with a from address of mydomain.com).

I already have SPF enabled but I can't make it too strict for various reasons unrelated this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python policyd-spf, you can enable strict SPF for specific domains only:

```
Reject_Not_Pass_Domains = mydomain.com
```

This will require SPF checks to 'pass' for the listed domains, while still having a relaxed policy for everyone else.

Alternatively, you could maybe block the domain entirely using `check_sender_access` in `smtpd_sender_restrictions`; do it in master.cf, making sure to only apply it to port 25 (server-to-server) and not port 587 (client-server, for outgoing mail).

Comment: Thanks, I think the spf answer does what I want.  btw how do I only apply something to port 25 in master.cf?

Comment: A stock master.cf already has examples for policy specific to port 587 (submission).